# Connecting Android app with web (and using the same database)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications

I made an android app using **Firebase** as the main database, specifically the **RealtimeDatabase**.
I've handled the authentication of the users with Firebase authentication.

---

Thanks to those who advised me to include a better description of the problem (i'm new here).

I built an app with android studio and connected it to firebase realtime database.
Is an app that is used to *share gift lists*, users access the app and can send each other their lists and view them from the app.
The **problem** arises when a **user shares the list with those who do not have the app**:
i would like a link to be generated, showing a web version of the list, where the app actions are still available (which obviously are actions involving the use of firebase).
I don't know how to do it...

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  You can access a single Firebase product from an number of web or mobile applications added to that project. Are you having problems adding a web app to your project, as explained in the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. If you're having problems getting it to work, edit your question to show the [minimal code that anyone can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: stackoverflow associated my question with a similar question, but doesn’t resolve my question, so i edited the first version :)